# QueryException in Laravel 5 when executing Model::create

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, frameworks

I a newbie to Laravel. In my project there is a Model called Student and a table in MySQL student.

When I am trying to insert some values to the database using Student::create , it gives me the following errors.

The database table exists and I retrieved some values from another table before.

My Insert Code in the Controller:

```
Student::create([
    'name' => Input::get('student_name'),
    'email' => Input::get('student_email',
    'contact' => Input::get('student_tel'),
    'reg_id' => Input::get('registration_no'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
]);
```

My Model Class:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model {

    protected $table = 'student';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'contact', 'username', 'password'];    
}
```

**Complete Error for QueryException**

> QueryException in Connection.php line 620: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table
>    or view not found: 1146 Table 'msc_project.tablename' doesn't exist
>    (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where
>    `registration_no` = asgfsag)

```
``**in Connection.php line 620
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 576
at Connection->run('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 293
at Connection->select('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh'), true) in Builder.php line 1377
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1367
at Builder->getFresh(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1354
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1636
at Builder->aggregate('count', array('*')) in Builder.php line 1574
at Builder->count() in DatabasePresenceVerifier.php line 57
at DatabasePresenceVerifier->getCount('tablename', 'registration_no', 'ffhfdh', null, null, array()) in Validator.php line 1057
at Validator->validateUnique('registration_no', 'ffhfdh', array('tablename'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 372
at Validator->validate('registration_no', 'unique:tablename') in Validator.php line 325
at Validator->passes() in Validator.php line 347
at Validator->fails() in StudentController.php line 56
at StudentController->doRegistration()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StudentController), 'doRegistration'), array()) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('doRegistration', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(StudentController), object(Route), 'doRegistration') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(StudentController), object(Route), object(Request), 'doRegistration') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentController', 'doRegistration') in Route.php line 198
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/home/pranavaghanan/Documents/GitHub Projects/MScApp/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

**Complete Error List for PDOException**

> PDOException in Connection.php line 288: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table
>   or view not found: 1146 Table 'msc_project.tablename' doesn't exist

```
in Connection.php line 288
at PDO->prepare('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?') in Connection.php line 288
at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(object(MySqlConnection), 'select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh')) in Connection.php line 612
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 576
at Connection->run('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 293
at Connection->select('select count(*) as aggregate from `tablename` where `registration_no` = ?', array('ffhfdh'), true) in Builder.php line 1377
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1367
at Builder->getFresh(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1354
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1636
at Builder->aggregate('count', array('*')) in Builder.php line 1574
at Builder->count() in DatabasePresenceVerifier.php line 57
at DatabasePresenceVerifier->getCount('tablename', 'registration_no', 'ffhfdh', null, null, array()) in Validator.php line 1057
at Validator->validateUnique('registration_no', 'ffhfdh', array('tablename'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 372
at Validator->validate('registration_no', 'unique:tablename') in Validator.php line 325
at Validator->passes() in Validator.php line 347
at Validator->fails() in StudentController.php line 56
at StudentController->doRegistration()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StudentController), 'doRegistration'), array()) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('doRegistration', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(StudentController), object(Route), 'doRegistration') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(StudentController), object(Route), object(Request), 'doRegistration') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\StudentController', 'doRegistration') in Route.php line 198
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/home/pranavaghanan/Documents/GitHub Projects/MScApp/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

**UPDATE :**

I just found out that when comment out the code which is for Validation, the data goes into the database. Any idea why this line is causing the error?

```
$validator = \Validator::make($postedData, $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) { 
    return Redirect::to('registration')->withInput()->withErrors($validator); 
}
```

If I don't use \Validator it doesn't accept the class either.

Comment: Are you sure that the table called as `student`, not `students`? By convention it should be `students`.

Comment: Yh. I have checked it. The table in the database is called student. This is the code for the migration. Schema::create('student', function(Blueprint $table).

Comment: Check using PMA that the table actually exist ? btw the `tablename` mentioned here is something you edited to not showing us or is it the real error?

Comment: @Gal I didn't edit anything. It is the real error.

I just commented out some section which does the validation and the code goes into the database. :-/

Comment: Laravel is a mess. don't waste your time.